# Javascript can't parse the json properly

Tags: javascript, django, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to parse json with xhr. I've done xhr file for two pages and every page takes different data from xhr file. If the parser can't find the proper id in html template it can't handle the remaining part.

Here's js

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
method = 'GET'
xhr.responseType = 'json'

function buildTable(data){
        
}

xhr.open(method, requestURL)
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status > 400){
        console.error(xhr.error)
    }else{
        console.log(xhr.response)
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = xhr.response.name 
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = xhr.response.status
        ....
        buildTable(xhr.response.history)
        document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = xhr.response.description
    }
}
xhr.send()
```

and here's the django template

```
{% extends 'base_dashboard.html' %}

<div class="wrapper">
        {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
            <div id='name'></div>
            <div class="" id="status">In Progress</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12" id='description'></div>
</div>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static '/js/xhr_dashboard.js' %}">
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

JSON example

```
name: "myname"
description: "This is the test description"
status: "2"
```

Comment: may you share an example of that JSON? You also don't seem to be parsing any JSON?

Comment: @evolutionxbox anyway it's not about json parsing. The question is more about js assigning to the corresponding id in html

Comment: I think it is about parsing. `response.name` is likely to be undefined if `response` is not parsed. Also the JSON example is not JSON, it looks more like YAML.

Comment: _"it's not about json parsing"_ - Then why is the title just about that: _"Javascript can't parse the json properly"_ ?

Comment: For a quick solution you probably need `const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);` then `document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = data.name;` and so on. In the long run you should use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: Does it answer help you? your js file may run before the page load. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105685/14032355